# How to get binary representations of strings in Shell?

Tags: shell, shell-script, java, openssl, binary

I'm using `openssl dgst -sha1 -binary` to get hash values of my strings in binary format.

(I'm using `-binary` flag because my version of openssl adds "stdout" before each hash value on default output, and `-binary` helps to avoid it, therefore it's easier to store hash results in binary format for further processing (so I can just use `xxd -p` when I want hex values instead of manually cutting out that "`stdout`" from each string)

So, the binary output of `openssl dgst -sha1 -binary` for a "Hello!" string in Cygwin console will look like this: _▒▒"q▒%▒a▒▒▒▒.&C▒0N▒Q▒▒vH&8i

Now I create a new variable with this result and concatenate it with another variable, which value is not in binary format (i.e. "World"). So my new variable now looks like

_▒▒"q▒%▒a▒▒▒▒.&C▒0N▒Q▒▒vH&8iWorld

Then I generate another hash for this concatenated string and compare it to the one I got using default Java hashing libraries (`MessageDigest`). On this step, however, hashes obtained via shell and Java don't match (and I need to get exactly the same value as the one generated on Java side).

So I suppose that my "World" string should be in binary format as well to match my Java hash output (because as long as I generate hashes for concatenated binary values all hashes match). However, I don't know how to convert my "World" string to binary format in shell. Any ideas?

Comment: To be clear: You are generating a hash, adding a salt and then hashing the whole thing again? O.o

Comment: @muru Yes. And there's no way I can change it (although I'd love to), I can only adapt my shell script to match values from existing Java code.

Comment: I'm _sure_ there's a better way to do this, even on Cygwin... What's the final **hex** output produced by the Java code when you feed it `"Hello!"` and `"World"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't store *binary* data (binary data generally refers to data with arbitrary byte values, not only byte values that form valid characters but is not special otherwise) in `bash` variables as `bash` doesn't support storing the `0` byte value in its variables (and remember you can't pass such strings in arguments to commands as those are NUL delimited strings).

You can in `zsh` though. Also remember that command substitution strips trailing newline characters (0xa bytes, maybe different on Cygwin), so it's probably better to use `read` here:

```
$ echo 323 | openssl dgst -sha1 -binary | hd
00000000  3a 8b 03 4a 5d 00 e9 07  b2 9e 0a 61 b3 54 db 45  |:..J]......a.T.E|
00000010  63 4b 37 b0                                       |cK7.|
00000014
```

See how that contains both a 0 byte and newline character (0xa)

```
$ echo 323 | openssl dgst -sha1 -binary | IFS= LC_ALL=C read -ru0 -k20 var &&
  var=${var}World
$ printf %s $var | hd
00000000  3a 8b 03 4a 5d 00 e9 07  b2 9e 0a 61 b3 54 db 45  |:..J]......a.T.E|
00000010  63 4b 37 b0 57 6f 72 6c  64                       |cK7.World|
00000019
```

Note again that you can only pass that variable to builtin commands (`printf`...).

Now, if all you want is hash it again, then it's just

```
(echo 323 | openssl dgst -sha1 -binary; printf %s World) |
  openssl dgst -sha1 -binary
```

no need for a variable.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation!
However, I tried using
 
`(printf %s World | echo -n Hello openssl dgst -sha1 -binary; ) |
  openssl dgst -sha1 -binary | xxd -p`


And the value still didn't match. I also tried `echo -n` to avoid empty lines and I added xxd -p for output in hex. 

My code is slightly different from yours because in fact I want the result to look like SHA1(World+SHA1(Hello)), not vice versa. Did I change your code correctly? And I see that you are using both `printf %s` and `echo,` there must be a reason for that, right? What is the difference?

Comment: @C_U Then: `(printf %s World; printf %s Hello | sha1) | sha1`. piping things to `echo` doesn't make sense. `echo` doesn't _read_ anything, it _writes_ its argument (after transformation which is one of the reasons why you should use `printf` instead).